Ускорить процесс получения кроп, посредством ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i FILE -ss 10 -t 2 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  \$NF }' | tail -1

Возвращает что то похожее на
crop=124:1424:12:12

Берем видеофайла, указываем что смотреть необходимо на кадры с 10с по 12с...
Данный процесс занимает весьма продолжительное время, это при том что смотрим мы с 10с по 12 секунду...
В идеале, время тут лучше не указывать. Предположим продолжительность видео 1 час, то операция будет занимать не менее 5мин...
Ищу решение, при котором точно также возможно взять кроп по видео, но операция займет куда меньшее время...
